# Ansible Vault inline variable with to_nice_json: Unexpected templating type error occurred...not JSON serializable

Tags: json, templates, ansible, jinja2, ansible-vault

I typically configure my projects by settings configuration variables in `vars/main.yml` and rendering a subset of those out to a JSON via `to_nice_json`.

Consider an example of the `vars/main.yaml` like the one below:

```
  # Application Configuration Settings.
  config:

    dev:
      # General Settings.
      logger_level: DEBUG

      # PostgreSQL Server Configuration Settings.
      sql_host: "localhost"
      sql_port: 5432
      sql_username: "someuser"
      sql_password: "somepassword"
      sql_db: "somedb"
```

which I render out via a Jinja2 template and the `template` module with the following content:

```
{{ config.dev | to_nice_json }}
```

Recently I tried to use Ansible Vault to encrypt the sensitive bits, e.g., the `sql_password` through the `encrypt_string` command as such:

`ansible-vault encrypt_string --vault-id .ansible-vault-password "somepassword" --name 'sql_password'`

and inline the encrypted version directly in the YAML file like this:

```
# Application Configuration Settings.
config:

    dev:
      # General Settings.
      logger_level: DEBUG

      # PostgreSQL Server Configuration Settings.
      sql_host: "localhost"
      sql_port: 5432
      sql_username: "someuser"
      sql_password: !vault |
      $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
      35383832623937353934636538306539623336633336643430396662323161333838333463653764
      3839653635326166303636643664333466376236626137310a323839373862626237643162303535
      35333966383834356239376566356263656635323865323466306362323864356663383661333262
      3165643733633262650a663363653832373936383033306137633234626264353538356630336131
      3063
      sql_db: "somedb"
```

However, when the `to_nice_json` filter is applied I get the following error:

```
fatal: [myrole]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleError: Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({{ config.dev | to_nice_json }}\n): somepassword' is not JSON serializable"}
```

As can be see, the variable is property decrypted but it errors out when serialising to JSON. If I wrap the inline vault variable in double-quotes, however, the decryption doesn't happen and the resulting JSON contains the entire vault blob.

Am I missing something? Is this issue with the `to_nice_json` filter or am inlining it the wrong way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a workaround for such problems extract the vaulted value to a separate variable (as opposed to a value of a key in a dictionary):

```
vars:
  my_sql_password: !vault | 
    $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
    5383832623937353934636538306539623336633336643430396662323161333838333463653764
    3839653635326166303636643664333466376236626137310a323839373862626237643162303535
    35333966383834356239376566356263656635323865323466306362323864356663383661333262
    3165643733633262650a663363653832373936383033306137633234626264353538356630336131
    3063
  # Application Configuration Settings.
  config:
    dev:
      # General Settings.
      logger_level: DEBUG

      # PostgreSQL Server Configuration Settings.
      sql_host: "localhost"
      sql_port: 5432
      sql_username: "someuser"
      sql_password: "{{ my_sql_password }}"
      sql_db: "somedb"
```

Comment: Right you are! By defining the encrypted variables outside the portion that gets serialized to JSON and interpolating the decrypted result into a string it works great. Do you know if this is a known issue in Ansible? If so, could you provide a link or something?